# Passing a value to an sql child request

Tags: sql

I am currently working on an SQL request that I cannot get to work ...

It is a request which contains several joins and also a child request (a second SELECT which is in an INNER JOIN).

My problem is that my second SELECT makes reference to an element of the SELECT parent and it seems that it is not possible:

```
Error: Field 'account_extra.id_schedule' unknown in on clause
```

I can't see how I can work around the problem.
Is there a solution to transmit the value of '' account_extra.id_schedule 'to SELECT which is in the INNER JOIN? Or how to do it differently?

```
     SELECT * FROM distance
     LEFT JOIN account_extra ON account_extra.account_extra_id = distance.id_account_extra AND account_extra.account_extra_is_visible = 1
     LEFT JOIN city ON account_extra.id_city = city.city_id
     RIGHT JOIN job_like ON job_like.id_account_extra = account_extra.account_extra_id AND job_like.id_job = 37
     LEFT JOIN job ON job.job_id = job_like.id_job
     INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT (
                          GREATEST(a.lu000 - b.lu000, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu005 - b.lu005, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu010 - b.lu010, 0) +
                          GREATEST(a.lu015 - b.lu015, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu020 - b.lu020, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu025 - b.lu025, 0)
                         ) AS Schedule_correspondence FROM schedule AS a
                 INNER JOIN schedule AS b ON (a.schedule_id = 115 AND b.schedule_id = account_extra.id_schedule)
     ) AS x
     WHERE id_shop = 56 AND distance_km < account_extra.account_extra_action_perimeter
```

Comment: Mixing `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` makes queries much more difficult to follow.  You should provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Which dbms? (has that error message...)

Comment: It's probably MySQL, but the error is in the syntax.

Comment: Yes is MySQL. The error is that it does not recognize "account_extra.id_schedule" in the second SELECT

Comment: Syntax problems put aside, you probably can include `b.schedule_id` in inner select, use aggregation by its value and use it in outer join operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you can't use tables part of the "outer" set of joins from within the "inner" (nested) join.

The following query should address this specific problem but as you may notice adds a column to the inner join, meaning you may not be able to use `*` in your `SELECT` clause.
Also note that depending on the amount of data in the `schedule` table performance of this query may be quite bad.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    distance
    LEFT JOIN account_extra ON account_extra.account_extra_id = distance.id_account_extra AND account_extra.account_extra_is_visible = 1
    LEFT JOIN city ON account_extra.id_city = city.city_id
    RIGHT JOIN job_like ON job_like.id_account_extra = account_extra.account_extra_id AND job_like.id_job = 37
    LEFT JOIN job ON job.job_id = job_like.id_job
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            b.schedule_id,
            (
              GREATEST(a.lu000 - b.lu000, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu005 - b.lu005, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu010 - b.lu010, 0) +
              GREATEST(a.lu015 - b.lu015, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu020 - b.lu020, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu025 - b.lu025, 0)
            ) AS Schedule_correspondence
        FROM
            schedule AS a
            INNER JOIN schedule AS b ON (a.schedule_id = 115)
     ) AS x ON (x.schedule_id = account_extra.id_schedule)
WHERE
    id_shop = 56
    AND distance_km < account_extra.account_extra_action_perimeter
```

---

EDIT NOTES: an edit to the original question made the below portion of answer outdated and no longer valid. I'm leaving it here for reference only.

---

If you re-format your query, you will notice that you misplaced some brackets, leading to syntax errors.

Specifically, the error is in the section following the `INNER JOIN`. This results in the parser detecting there is something wrong once it reaches `account_extra.id_schedule`.

It's hard to tell how to fix this specific query, but I can at least format it a bit better to help understanding where the "messy part" is.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    distance
    LEFT JOIN account_extra ON account_extra.account_extra_id = distance.id_account_extra AND account_extra.account_extra_is_visible = 1
    LEFT JOIN city          ON account_extra.id_city = city.city_id
    RIGHT JOIN job_like     ON job_like.id_account_extra = account_extra.account_extra_id AND job_like.id_job = 37
    LEFT JOIN job           ON job.job_id = job_like.id_job
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            (
                GREATEST(a.lu000 - b.lu000, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu005 - b.lu005, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu010 - b.lu010, 0) +
                GREATEST(a.lu015 - b.lu015, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu020 - b.lu020, 0) +  GREATEST(a.lu025 - b.lu025, 0)
            )
    ) AS Schedule_correspondence FROM schedule AS a
    INNER JOIN schedule AS b ON (a.schedule_id = 115 AND b.schedule_id = account_extra.id_schedule)) AS x
WHERE
    id_shop = 56
    AND distance_km < account_extra.account_extra_action_perimeter
```

As you can see, the first `INNER JOIN` is closed before any table is used in its inner query. Additionally, the subsequent `INNER JOIN` has an extra bracket just before `AS x` with no corresponding open bracket.

Comment: yes I made an error in the closings of the parantheses, I have now corrected it in the question. Unfortunately I still have this problem of "account_extra.id_schedule" not recognized in the second SELECT

Comment: I see you corrected the brackets. There is however your core issue remaining, that stems from the impossibility to use columns of "outer" tables from within an "inner" query. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an alias for account_extra `... LEFT JOIN account_extra AS ae ...` Then use the alias in the subselect. Without the alias it doesn't have enough context to bind the values. Or add an alias for the id itself in the query.

Will depend on your DBMS though.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything, I get the SQL error message: 'ae.id_schedule' unknown. Perhaps it is not possible to make a link between the parent aliases and the aliases of the child SELECT ...